# How to keep the values of one column per index?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following Pandas dataframe:

```py
   col_a  col_b  col_c
0   10     15     20
0   10     15     20
1   10     15     20
1   10     15     20
1   10     15     20
1   10     15     20
2   10     15     20
```

Now, let's consider that we'd like the following mapping:

```
{
  0: 'col_a',
  1: 'col_b',
  2: 'col_c'
}
```

The mapping essentially dictates which column we shall keep for each index!

Output `df`:

```py
  column
0   10
0   10
1   15
1   15
1   15
1   15
2   20
```

So far, I have something like this:

```py
keep_cols = [(0, 'col_a'), (1, 'col_b'), (2, 'col_c')]

output = pd.concat([df.loc[df['index_col'] == idx, col] for idx, col in keep_cols], axis=1)
```

However, I am creating sub-dfs before actually concatenating them back, which I guess is sub-optimal as far as performance is concerned!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup) with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html):

```
mapper = {
  0: 'col_a',
  1: 'col_b',
  2: 'col_c'
}

idx, cols = pd.factorize(df.index.map(mapper))

df['column'] = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
```

Output:

```
   col_a  col_b  col_c  column
0     10     15     20      10
0     10     15     20      10
1     10     15     20      15
1     10     15     20      15
1     10     15     20      15
1     10     15     20      15
2     10     15     20      20
```

If you want a Series or new DataFrame as output:

```
out = pd.Series(df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx], index=df.index)

# or
out = pd.DataFrame({'column': df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]}, index=df.index)
```

Output:

```
# Series
0    10
0    10
1    15
1    15
1    15
1    15
2    20
dtype: int64

# DataFrame
   column
0      10
0      10
1      15
1      15
1      15
1      15
2      20
```

##### alternative

For fun, here is another alternative using a [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), if you have exactly one match per row:

```
# stack the dataframe
s = df.stack()

# identify the matches
m = s.index.get_level_values(0).map(mapper) == s.index.get_level_values(1)

# keep only the matches
out = s[m].droplevel(1)
```

Output:

```
0    10
0    10
1    15
1    15
1    15
1    15
2    20
dtype: int64
```

##### limits

If you have indices without a match, `factorize` will return `-1` and this will be mapped incorrectly, you should then use:

```
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df.index.map(mapper))

df['column'] = np.where(idx>=0,
                        df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx],
                        np.nan)
```

With the alternative solution, you wouldn't be able to `reindex` (`s[m].droplevel(1).reindex(df.index)`) as you have duplicated indices, and this would raise an error.

Example:

```
   col_a  col_b  col_c  column
0     10     15     20    10.0
0     10     15     20    10.0
1     10     15     20    15.0
1     10     15     20    15.0
1     10     15     20    15.0
1     10     15     20    15.0
2     10     15     20    20.0
3      6      7      8     NaN
```

Comment: I really liked the fun alternative! Could you please clarify about the one match per row? I missed that part a little bit.

Comment: @ttsak let me try to find an example

Comment: @ttsak I added an example to show you the limits if you have indices without mapping

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) with [looking up values by index/column labels](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels):

```
d = {
  0: 'col_a',
  1: 'col_b',
  2: 'col_c'
}

idx, cols = pd.factorize(df.index.map(d))
df['column'] = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
```

Or use `rename`:

```
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df.rename(d).index)
df['column'] = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
```

---

```
print (df)
   col_a  col_b  col_c  column
0     10     15     20      10
0     10     15     20      10
1     10     15     20      15
1     10     15     20      15
1     10     15     20      15
1     10     15     20      15
2     10     15     20      20
```

For one column DataFrame pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
d = {
  0: 'col_a',
  1: 'col_b',
  2: 'col_c'
}

idx, cols = pd.factorize(df.rename(d).index)
arr = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]

df = pd.DataFrame({'column':arr}, index=df.index)
print (df)
   column
0      10
0      10
1      15
1      15
1      15
1      15
2      20
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([np.array(df.loc[y]) for y in zip(d.keys(), d.values())]),
             index=df.index, columns=['col'])
```

Output:

```
   col
0   10
0   10
1   15
1   15
1   15
1   15
2   20
```